# Is there a way to set a password on a dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox, password-protection

I have a basic Dropbox account with 150GB free due to promotions of Samsung devices, school, friend referrals, etc.

I'm sharing that account with my mother and my girlfriend because I have so much space that I'm not using only using 22GB and they're each using 4GB and 6GB and they each have their own folders with their names on Dropbox.

Is there a way I can put a password on my own folder in case I want to upload something I don't want them to see?

They're using it on their laptops and smartphones, so do I.

Comment: Searching for "password protect dropbox folder" gives a number of interesting links to look at ...

Comment: These searches only protect your dropbox folder on a pc but not on their mobile app

Comment: Then you clearly haven't read the following link http://www.howtogeek.com/129393/6-ways-to-secure-your-dropbox-account/ which suggests encrypting your drop files ... "If you’re looking for something a bit more user friendly with mobile apps, BoxCryptor is also an excellent solution. "

Comment: The trick would have been only to share their own folders to each of them, not the whole thing. In effect, you gave them root level access

Comment: This question is not about the Dropbox web interface but rather about securing local storage. It should not be migrated to Web Apps.

Comment: @Tetsujin: That won’t work because it applies their storage constraint as well: [“The size of a shared folder will be counted against the quota of every member of that folder”](https://www.dropbox.com/help/59?path=space_and_storage).

Comment: @DanielB - makes sense; hadn't considered it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. When you share a folder, it counts against that user's storage quota. If you put your Dropbox account on their computer, you can perform a selective sync to only sync specific folders. It is not fool proof as they can sync more folders they want (folders that you do not want them to access).

https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/59

You can encrypt the files on your end. Although, they would have access, it would look like junk files and perhaps even junk names.

Answer (score 2):

No, there’s no such thing. You’ll have to use an encrypted container (TrueCrypt, Bitlocker-encrypted VHD, ...) or archive (password-protected ZIP, 7z, ...). Of course, this will severely restrict convenience and access from mobile devices.

Comment: [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) can set password to and encrypt file names in the archive.